# Nested MySQL query to get admin _id>=3

Tags: mysql

This query seems does not seem to be working

```sql
    SELECT user_name,user_id, 
        (SELECT admin_id, COUNT(admin_id) as a 
         FROM `tb_user` 
         GROUP BY admin_id 
         HAVING a>=3) 
    FROM `tb_user` WHERE 1
```

I want to get a list of `user_name` and `user_id` with such `admin_id` (having `a>=3`)

I should use join to solve this I think, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Help us help you - share the table structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for this sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join rather than putting the subquery in the select list.

```
select t1.user_name, t1.user_id
FROM tb_user AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT admin_id
    FROM tb_user
    GROUP BY admin_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
) AS t2 ON t1.admin_id = t2.admin_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using `exists`:

```
select user_name, user_id
from tb_user t
where exists (
    select 1
    from tb_user t2
    where t2.admin_id = t.admin_id
    group by t2.admin_id
    having count(*) >= 3
    )
```

Comment: Don't you need to correlate the subquery?

Comment: @Barmar Yep thanks.  `join`, `exists` and `in` are all potential options (although could produce slightly different results with nulls).  Thx for pointing that out though.

Comment: Can you wxplain on how the query flow works?

Comment: @ashwinyadav - sure, this says return any users from `tb_user` where their `admin_id` exists in the subquery.  The subquery only returns admins that exist with at least 3 records in the same table.